# Dev-C++ res error

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{ 
    int num1 = 15;
    int num2 = 5;
    int res
    res = num1 + num2;

    printf("Content of variable res: \n", var1);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I tried compiling and running the program and it said error on

> res = num1 + num2

Comment: Where you have declared `var1`?

Comment: title dev c++, tagged as c ?

Comment: Dev-C++ is the program I used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a missing semi-colon:

```
int res
```

Do this:

```
int res;
     //^--Missing
res = num1 + num2;
```

Or quite simply

```
int res = num1 + num2;
```

Also what in the world is `var1` and also there is no format specifier in `printf` (`%d` for `int`)

```
printf("Content of variable res: \n", var1);
                                      //^-- undeclared this should also be an error
```

It should be:

```
printf("Content of variable res: %d\n", res);
```

Comment: Oh, sorry I just started C Programming, not familiar with the coding. Thank you very much for the infos. Btw, while trying to compile and run I received an error http://prntscr.com/3s1kw3

Comment: @user3733379 - No need to be sorry, everyone starts off - here is your working code http://ideone.com/cw4Sw2